# How to combine multiple numpy masks

Tags: python, numpy

```
m1 = [0,1,1,3]
m2 = [0,0,1,1]
data = [10,20,30,40]
```

I want to do something like this:

```
mask = (m1 == 1) & (m2 == 1)
data[mask] #should return 30
```

Note, this example results in an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying multiple masks to arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536367/applying-multiple-masks-to-arrays)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are using python lists instead of numpy arrays. Try this instead:

```
import numpy as np

m1 = np.array([0,1,1,3])
m2 = np.array([0,0,1,1])

mask = (m1 == 1) & (m2 == 1)
data[mask]
# returns array([30])
```

In your example, when `m1` was a list, `m1 == 1` is evaluated as `False` (the same for `m2`), so mask was `False` and `data[False] = data[0] = 10`.

Comment: I get the error TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe' . My dataset it float32, could that be a problem?

Comment: Are you sure both m1 and m2 are arrays of some time? If one of them is an object array, you can't compare them to 1. Just use the interactive shell to find out what `m1 == 1` and `m2 == 1` evaluate to.

Comment: @tiago When I try to perform the same operation on a multi dimensional matrix which the `OpenCV` converts an image to using `yuv_object1 = (yuv_image > lowerLimit).astype(np.float32) | (yuv_image > upperLimit).astype(np.float32)` I get this error `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: @Santhosh don't use `.astype(np.float32)`

Comment: https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/8c9bcc3cf640524c4c20a9c40e89cb6a2f2fa0e9/PythonAPI/pycocotools/mask.py#L77

Comment: If you get the `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and'...`, you might have skipped the parentheses - they are necessary here.