# Maximum and minimum values numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

if I have an array like

```
z = np.random.random((41,61,106))
y,x=np.mgrid[slice(0,61, 1),slice(0,106, 1)] 
z=z[_num,x,y]]
```

Who I can capture the 10 maximum and 10 minimum and mask the rest of the values in a array z.

And, it is posible take the midle of the max and the min values an put another 10 values.

```
 middle=sorted[(len(sorted)/2)-5:(len(sorted)/2)+5]
 print middle
 mask = ma.masked_inside(z,sorted[10],sorted[-10],middle)
 print mask
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not quite understand the code snippet. To answer your first question:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

z = np.random.random((10,10))
sorted = np.sort(z,axis=None)
mask = ma.masked_inside(z,sorted[10],sorted[-10])
```

concerning your second question you might also consider concatenating the conditions

```
ma.masked_where( ((z<sorted[sorted.size/2-5]) |
                  (z>sorted[sorted.size/2+4])) &
                 ((z>sorted[10]) & (z<sorted[-10])),z)
```

Comment: Thank you!! works. I edit the answer and include one more petition , if you dont mind that take 10 values between max and min, in the middle take 10 most near.

Comment: My code that Take 10 values in the middle not works. yours yes.

Comment: And how I can retrieve the position in the 2 dimensional array? of the elements masked

Comment: the last code yours give me     _f_data= ma.masked_where( ((z<sorted[sorted.size/2-5]) | (z>sorted[sorted.size/2+4])) & ((z>sorted[10]) & (z<sorted[-10])),z)
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: when Apply sort to a array with a mask, the give me in _sorted[-10] elements "--"

Comment: There is a related question here: [how-to-combine-multiple-numpy-masks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579260/how-to-combine-multiple-numpy-masks) Check whether you really compare arrays. You can test every single condition on its own in the interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a few of the items in an array to be sorted, with numpy >= 1.8 it is more efficient to use [`np.partition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) than `np.sort`:

```
In [6]: z = np.random.rand(61, 106)

In [7]: %timeit np.sort(z, axis=None)
1000 loops, best of 3: 413 µs per loop

In [8]: %%timeit
    ...: n = z.size
    ...: y = np.partition(z, (10, n//2 - 5, n//2 + 5, -10), axis=None)
    ...: y[:10].sort()
    ...: y[n//2 - 5:n//2 + 5].sort()
    ...: y[-10:].sort()
    ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 µs per loop
```

Comment: hello, thank you, . How I return the value,index of the elements masked