# How to read an (image, label, segm) tuple from the training dataset with COCOInstance?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
train_dataset = dset.CocoDetection(root = path2data,
                                 annFile = path2json)
```

After this function, I want to get these three outputs using train_dataset but it doesn't work.

```
train_image, train_label, train_segm = train_dataset[6]
```

I am currently getting two outputs as a result of train_dataset image and traget.

I need train_image, train_label, train_segm to perform the operations I want to use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can get there in a single step.

As the getitem code in https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/coco.html#CocoDetection.__getitem__ indicated, the loader gives you only image and target (annotationIds).

You then have to convert the annotationIds into segments using something along the lines of [COCO annotations to masks - For instance segmentation model training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508769/coco-annotations-to-masks-for-instance-segmentation-model-training)

Comment: I'm having problems with gluoncv.
After the index is created in the document I left below
train_image, train_label, train_segm = train_dataset[6]
3 outputs can be obtained using this expression.
after i create index with dset.CocoDetection
img, target = train_dataset[6]
I can get output like this.

I have to fix this problem so I can continue with gluoncv.
https://cv.gluon.ai/build/examples_instance/train_mask_rcnn_coco.html#data-loader