# Replace a Color Threshold within Numpy Image - Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image that I am preparing for OCR. I am using opencv2 (which includes numpy). I am trying to convert the "yellow" text to black, and everything in the background to white. My yellow text is varying amounts of darker and lighter yellow pixels, so I need to compare a threshold, not a single RGB/BGR value. I have seen some [examples online](https://answers.opencv.org/question/97416/replace-a-range-of-colors-with-a-specific-color-in-python/) showing how to change a static colour but I'm unsure how to apply this using a threshold.

Here is a sample picture:

[Sample Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b25iY.png)

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("Text.png")
print(type(image)) # type is a <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

# Convert any existing black pixels to white.
image[np.where((image == [0, 0, 0]).all(axis=2))] = [255, 255, 255] # BGR format

# Convert any "yellow" pixels to black (any text)
image[np.where((image <= [0, 209, 255]).all(axis=2)) and (image >= [0, 56, 68]).all(axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0] # BGR format

# Convert any non black pixels to white (background pixels)
image[np.where((image > [0, 0, 0]).any(axis=2))] = [255, 255, 255] # BGR format
```

This code generates the below picture:

[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6RPh.png)

We can see my code nearly works, but my second step converts any white pixels to black pixels (notice the extra black pixels below letters). This should not happen (and there might be other problems??).

Can someone explain where I have gone wrong and how I can fix this? I'm a beginner with numpy arrays and it's syntax, so extra detail will be a big help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can create more than one array.

Comment: Also, you can write `img[(img == [0, 0, 0]).all(axis=-1)] = (255, 255, 255)` directly instead of using `np.where`.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I tried the below. This still doesn't solve the problem though.

`image[(image == [0, 0, 0]).all(axis=2)] = [255, 255, 255]

image[np.where((image <= [0, 209, 255]).all(axis=2)) and (image >= [0, 56, 68]).all(axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0] # [0, 0, 0]

image[(image > [0, 0, 0]).any(axis=2)] = [255, 255, 255]`

Comment: Also, I just noticed you're using `and`. That should probably be a `&`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579260/how-to-combine-multiple-numpy-masks. You can also remove the `np.where` around the second step.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I changed it to: 
    `image[(image == [0, 0, 0]).all(axis=2)] = [255, 255, 255]
    image[(image <= [0, 209, 255]).all(axis=2) & (image >= [0, 56, 68]).all(axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0] # [0, 0, 0]
    image[(image > [0, 0, 0]).any(axis=2)] = [255, 255, 255]`

This seems to have change the output drastically. It's not the result I'm after but I need some time to work out if there is some other error or if I just need to refine the thresholds.

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq So it seems the above code (the second line) is only converting pixels values exactly equal to [0, 209, 255] and [0, 56, 68] to black. I need to convert all pixels within this range (threshhold) to black, so all the varying yellow pixels are changed.

Comment: The "yellow" pixels in your image seem to contain some blue component as well. But your blue interval in the second step is `[0, 0]`.

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq  Ahh of course, the B values were incorrect! Thanks very much for your help!! This works perfectly! Not sure how to "honor" or thank you on this forum.